# How to make a parameter in a function, to be optional and have an unlimited amounts of parameters

Tags: python, function

How can I make it so that a function in python has an unknown amount of parameters while being optional at the same time?

```
python
def make_cool_keybaord(keycaps_language, ???):
    #??? should be rgb_colors, but I don't know how to make it optional and have an unknown amount of parameters at the same time
    
    colors = []
    if len(rgb_colors) > 0:
        for i in rgb_colors:
            colors.append(i)
            
    
    print("your keyboard has keycaps in the lanuguage of {} and has rgb colors of {}".format(keycaps_language,colors ))


make_cool_keybaord('english',???)
```

--How it should work:

make_cool_keyboard('english','red','blue','yellow')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for non-keyword arguments or varargs in python, they can be defined by using the asterisk `*` operator.

```
def make_cool_keybaord(keycaps_language, *rgb_colors):
    
    colors = []
    if len(rgb_colors) > 0:
        for i in rgb_colors:
            colors.append(i)
        

    print("your keyboard has keycaps in the lanuguage of {} and has rgb colors of {}".format(keycaps_language,colors ))


make_cool_keybaord('english') #this is valid
make_cool_keybaord('english','red') #so is this
make_cool_keybaord('english','red','blue') #and this and so on
```

Comment: This works and answers my questions. Thank you, and have a good day.

Comment: If it answers your question, can you please select it as the answer and upvote so people looking for a similar problem can find it in the future?

Comment: it's okay! Good luck on your learning journey!

Comment: Thanks. Good luck with yours as well :)